# OpenGL context creation with the ARB extetion is not working

Tags: c, winapi, opengl

I want to create an OpenGL context using the ARB extention, but it doesn't works. The error messages printed in the console at runtime ( my puts() calls ) are : "Choosing the final window pixel format failed." and "Creating the final rendering context failed.". And the window doesn't dispalys.

When I remove the 3 last attributes of the array, the program doesn't output anything in the console but does not displays anything on the screen and then stops ( there is a while loop ). This is very weird.

The second function pointer retrieving with wglGetProcAddress() cast generates a warning when compiled with gcc and the -Wextra flag (for all warnings). I don't know why, if anyone can solve this please tell me.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <glew.h>

#include <GL\wglext.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK FirstWindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wp,
    LPARAM lp);
LRESULT CALLBACK FinalWindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wp,
    LPARAM lp);
unsigned int CreateShaderProgram(char* VertexSource, char* FragmentSource);

int main(void){
    WNDCLASSEX FirstWindowClass = {};
    FirstWindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    FirstWindowClass.style = CS_OWNDC;
    FirstWindowClass.lpfnWndProc = FirstWindowProcedure;
    FirstWindowClass.lpszClassName = L"FirstWindowClass";
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&FirstWindowClass))
        puts("Registration of the first window class failed.\n");

    HWND FirstWindow = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW,
        FirstWindowClass.lpszClassName, L"FirstWindow", WS_POPUP, 0, 0, 10, 10,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(FirstWindow == NULL)
        puts("Creation of the first window failed.\n");

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor = {};
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.nVersion = 1;
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |
        PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.cColorBits = 32;
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.cDepthBits = 24;
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.cStencilBits = 8;
    FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    HDC FirstWindowDeviceContext = GetDC(FirstWindow);
    if(FirstWindowDeviceContext == NULL)
        puts("First window device context retrieving failed.\n");

    int FirstWindowPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(FirstWindowDeviceContext,
        &FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor);
    if(FirstWindowPixelFormat == 0)
        puts("Choosing the first pixel format failed.\n");

    if(SetPixelFormat(FirstWindowDeviceContext, FirstWindowPixelFormat,
    &FirstWindowPixelFormatDescriptor) == FALSE)
        puts("Setting the first pixel format failed.\n");

    HGLRC FirstWindowRenderingContext =
        wglCreateContext(FirstWindowDeviceContext);
    if(FirstWindowRenderingContext == NULL)
        puts("Creating the first rendering context failed.\n");

    if(wglMakeCurrent(FirstWindowDeviceContext, FirstWindowRenderingContext) ==
    FALSE)
        puts("Making the first context current failed.\n");

    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        puts("Initialisation of GLEW failed.\n");

    WNDCLASSEX FinalWindowClass = {};
    FinalWindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    FinalWindowClass.style = CS_OWNDC;
    FinalWindowClass.lpfnWndProc = FinalWindowProcedure;
    FinalWindowClass.lpszClassName = L"FinalWindowClass";
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&FinalWindowClass))
        puts("Registration of the final window class failed\n");

    HWND FinalWindow = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW,
        FinalWindowClass.lpszClassName, L"FinalWindow", WS_POPUP, 0, 0, 10, 10,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if(FinalWindow == NULL)
        puts("Creation of the final window failed.\n");

    PFNWGLCHOOSEPIXELFORMATARBPROC wglChoosePixelFormatARB =
        wglGetProcAddress("wglChoosePixelFormatARB");
    if(wglChoosePixelFormatARB == NULL)
        puts("Getting the wglChoosePixelFormatARB function pointer failed.\n");

    PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC wglCreateContextAttribsARB =
        (PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC)
        wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB");
    if(wglCreateContextAttribsARB == NULL)
        puts("Getting the wglCreateContextAttribsARB function pointer"
            "failed.\n");

    int FinalWindowContextAttributes[] = {
        WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
        WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
        WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 24,
        WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
        WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        0,
    };

    HDC FinalWindowDeviceContext = GetDC(FinalWindow);
    if(FinalWindowDeviceContext == NULL)
        puts("Retrieving the final window device cotext failed.\n");

    int FinalWindowPixelFormat;
    if(FALSE == wglChoosePixelFormatARB(FinalWindowDeviceContext,
    FinalWindowContextAttributes, NULL, 1, &FinalWindowPixelFormat, NULL))
        puts("Choosing the final window pixel format failed.\n");

    HGLRC FinalWindowRenderingContext =
        wglCreateContextAttribsARB(FinalWindowDeviceContext, NULL,
        FinalWindowContextAttributes);
    if(FinalWindowRenderingContext == NULL)
        puts("Creating the final rendering context failed.\n");

    if(FALSE == wglMakeCurrent(FinalWindowDeviceContext,
    FinalWindowRenderingContext))
        puts("Making the final context current failed.\n");

    DWM_BLURBEHIND blur = {};
    blur.dwFlags = DWM_BB_ENABLE | DWM_BB_BLURREGION;
    blur.fEnable = 1;
    blur.hRgnBlur = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, -1, -1);
    DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow(FinalWindow, &blur);

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(FinalWindow, RGB(0, 0, 0), 255, LWA_COLORKEY);

    char VertexShaderSource[] =
    "#version 440 core\n"
    "\n"
    "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main(){\n"
    "   gl_Position = position;\n"
    "}";

    char FragmentShaderSource[] =
    "#version 440 core\n"
    "\n"
    "layout(location = 0) out vec4 colour;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main(){\n"
    "   colour = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);\n"
    "}";

    float Verticies[] = {
         0.0f,  0.5f, // top    : 0
         0.5f,  0.0f, // right  : 1
         0.0f, -0.5f, // bottom : 2
        -0.5f,  0.0f  // left   : 3
    };

    unsigned int Indices[] = {
        3, 0, 1, // top
        3, 2, 1  // bottom
    };

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    unsigned int VertexArray;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArray);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArray);

    unsigned int VertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * sizeof(float), Verticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    unsigned int IndexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &IndexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(unsigned int), Indices,
        GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);

    unsigned int ShaderProgram = CreateShaderProgram(VertexShaderSource,
        FragmentShaderSource);
    glUseProgram(ShaderProgram);

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 400);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    ShowWindow(FinalWindow, 1);

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
        wglSwapLayerBuffers(FinalWindowDeviceContext, WGL_SWAP_MAIN_PLANE);
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK FirstWindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp){
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wp, lp);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK FinalWindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp){
    switch(uMsg){
        case WM_NCHITTEST: return HTCAPTION;
        case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0); return 0;
        default: return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wp, lp);
    }
}

unsigned int CreateShader(char* Source, unsigned int Type);

unsigned int CreateShaderProgram(char* VertexSource,
char* FragmentSource){
    unsigned int ShaderProgram = glCreateProgram(),
        VertexShader = CreateShader(VertexSource, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
        FragmentShader = CreateShader(FragmentSource, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, VertexShader);
    glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, FragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(ShaderProgram);
    glValidateProgram(ShaderProgram);
    return ShaderProgram;
}

unsigned int CreateShader(char* Source, unsigned int Type){
    unsigned int Shader = glCreateShader(Type);
    glShaderSource(Shader, 1, (const char* const*)&Source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(Shader);
    return Shader;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use *glew.h*, I recommend to use "wglew.h", too. See [The OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html)

<s>`#include <wglext.h>`</s>

```c
#include <GL/wglew.h>
```

*wglew.h* handles the dynamic linking of the `wgl`* api. Thus you can skip invoking `wglGetProcAddress`:

```c
/*   DELETE

PFNWGLCHOOSEPIXELFORMATARBPROC wglChoosePixelFormatARB =
    (PFNWGLCHOOSEPIXELFORMATARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress("wglChoosePixelFormatARB");
if(wglChoosePixelFormatARB == NULL)
    puts("Getting the wglChoosePixelFormatARB function pointer failed.\n");

PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC wglCreateContextAttribsARB =
    (PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC)
    wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB");
if(wglCreateContextAttribsARB == NULL)
    puts("Getting the wglCreateContextAttribsARB function pointer"
        "failed.\n");
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
> ```

You need calling `glewInit()` again after `wglMakeCurrent()` for a final window, and it is desired destroying temporary window right away. Otherwise, GLEW will keep previous initialization state without Core Profile.

> int FinalWindowContextAttributes[] = {

As has been specified in previous question, `wglChoosePixelFormatARB()` and `wglCreateContextAttribsARB()` accept different list of attributes, so that you need creating to separate lists.

You may try the following `CreateCoreProfile()` method for creating OpenGL Core Profile (I suppose this is what you are looking for). The code snippet includes definitions from `wglext.h`, so that you may remove them in favor of `wglext.h`. It doesn't rely on GLEW, just WinAPI itself.

> ```
>     wglSwapLayerBuffers(FinalWindowDeviceContext, WGL_SWAP_MAIN_PLANE);
> ```

You should be really careful and consider using `SwapBuffers()` (without `wgl` prefix), as `wglSwapLayerBuffers()` may cause very weird behavior and not recommended by most sources I've seen. But I guess this is what you're looking for considering `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` calls.

> function pointer retrieving with wglGetProcAddress() cast generates a warning when compiled with gcc

This is a known GCC issue - WGL (`wglGetProcAddress()`), GLX and EGL APIs as many other define no other way for verifying signature of returned function pointer. Which is unsafe (application will crash on calling function having different signature), but there is nothing you can do to fix the warning - it can be only suppressed for now.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/gl.h>

//! Auxiliary tool creating WGL rendering context.
class WglWindow
{
private:
  #define GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION 0x8B8C

  // WGL_ARB_pixel_format
  #define WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB  0x2001
  #define WGL_DRAW_TO_BITMAP_ARB  0x2002
  #define WGL_ACCELERATION_ARB    0x2003
  #define WGL_SUPPORT_GDI_ARB     0x200F
  #define WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB  0x2010
  #define WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB   0x2011
  #define WGL_STEREO_ARB          0x2012
  #define WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB      0x2013
  #define WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB      0x2014
  #define WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB      0x2022
  #define WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB    0x2023

  #define WGL_NO_ACCELERATION_ARB      0x2025
  #define WGL_GENERIC_ACCELERATION_ARB 0x2026
  #define WGL_FULL_ACCELERATION_ARB    0x2027

  #define WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB       0x202B
  #define WGL_TYPE_COLORINDEX_ARB 0x202C

  // WGL_ARB_create_context_profile
  #define WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB 0x2091
  #define WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB 0x2092
  #define WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB         0x2094
  #define WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB  0x9126

  // WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS bits
  #define WGL_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB 0x0001
  #define WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB 0x0002

  // WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB bits
  #define WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB 0x00000001
  #define WGL_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB 0x00000002

  #define GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS 0x821D

  typedef const char* (WINAPI *wglGetExtensionsStringARB_t)(HDC theDeviceContext);
  typedef BOOL (WINAPI *wglChoosePixelFormatARB_t)(HDC theDevCtx, const int* theIntAttribs,
                                                   const float* theFloatAttribs, unsigned int theMaxFormats,
                                                   int* theFormatsOut, unsigned int* theNumFormatsOut);
  typedef HGLRC (WINAPI *wglCreateContextAttribsARB_t)(HDC theDevCtx, HGLRC theShareContext, const int* theAttribs);
  typedef const GLubyte* (WINAPI *glGetStringi_t) (GLenum name, GLuint index);

public:

  //! Create OpenGL Core Profile rendering context for specified window.
  static HGLRC CreateCoreProfile (HDC  theDevCtx,
                                  bool theIsDebugCtx)
  {
    HGLRC aGlCtx = NULL;
    {
      WglWindow aCtxTmp (L"wgltemp");
      if (!aCtxTmp.CreateDefaultWindow()) { return NULL; }
      const char* aWglExts = NULL;
      {
        wglGetExtensionsStringARB_t wglGetExtensionsStringARB = (wglGetExtensionsStringARB_t )wglGetProcAddress ("wglGetExtensionsStringARB");
        if (wglGetExtensionsStringARB != NULL) { aWglExts = wglGetExtensionsStringARB (aCtxTmp.myDevCtx); }
      }
      if (aWglExts == NULL) { return NULL; } // should never happen

      // in WGL world wglGetProcAddress() returns NULL if extensions is unavailable, so that checking for extension string can be skipped
      //if (checkGlExtension (aWglExts, "WGL_ARB_pixel_format"))
      //if (checkGlExtension (aWglExts, "WGL_ARB_create_context_profile"))
      wglChoosePixelFormatARB_t    aChoosePixProc = (wglChoosePixelFormatARB_t    )wglGetProcAddress ("wglChoosePixelFormatARB");
      wglCreateContextAttribsARB_t aCreateCtxProc = (wglCreateContextAttribsARB_t )wglGetProcAddress ("wglCreateContextAttribsARB");
      if (aCreateCtxProc == NULL) { return NULL; } // core profile cannot be created

      const int aPixAttribs[] =
      {
        WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB,  GL_TRUE,
        WGL_STEREO_ARB,         GL_FALSE,
        WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB,     WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
        WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB,     24,
        WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB,     24,
        WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB,   8,
        WGL_ACCELERATION_ARB,   WGL_FULL_ACCELERATION_ARB,
        0, 0,
      };
      unsigned int aFrmtsNb = 0;
      int aPixelFrmtId = 0;
      if (!aChoosePixProc (theDevCtx, aPixAttribs, NULL, 1, &aPixelFrmtId, &aFrmtsNb)
       ||  aPixelFrmtId == 0
       || !WglWindow::SetWindowPixelFormat (theDevCtx, aPixelFrmtId))
      {
        return NULL;
      }

      int aCoreCtxAttribs[] =
      {
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2,
        WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB,  WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB,         theIsDebugCtx ? WGL_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB : 0,
        0, 0
      };

      // Try to create the core profile of highest OpenGL version.
      // This will be done automatically by some drivers when requesting 3.2,
      // but some will not (e.g. AMD Catalyst) since WGL_ARB_create_context_profile specification allows both implementations.
      for (int aLowVer4 = 7; aLowVer4 >= 0 && aGlCtx == NULL; --aLowVer4)
      {
        aCoreCtxAttribs[1] = 4; aCoreCtxAttribs[3] = aLowVer4;
        aGlCtx = aCreateCtxProc (theDevCtx, NULL, aCoreCtxAttribs);
      }
      for (int aLowVer3 = 3; aLowVer3 >= 2 && aGlCtx == NULL; --aLowVer3)
      {
        aCoreCtxAttribs[1] = 3; aCoreCtxAttribs[3] = aLowVer3;
        aGlCtx = aCreateCtxProc (theDevCtx, NULL, aCoreCtxAttribs);
      }
    }
    if (aGlCtx != NULL)
    {
      if (!::wglMakeCurrent (theDevCtx, aGlCtx)) { std::cerr << "Error: unable to bind context\n"; }
    }   
    return aGlCtx;
  }

public:

  //! Empty constructor.
  WglWindow (const wchar_t* theName) : myWin (NULL), myDevCtx (NULL), myGlCtx (NULL) {}

  //! Destructor.
  ~WglWindow() { Release(); }

  //! Release resources.
  void Release()
  {
    //wglMakeCurrent (NULL, NULL);
    if (myWin != NULL && myDevCtx != NULL) { ::ReleaseDC (myWin, myDevCtx); myDevCtx = NULL; }
    if (myGlCtx != NULL) { ::wglDeleteContext (myGlCtx); myGlCtx = NULL; }
    if (myWin   != NULL) { ::DestroyWindow (myWin); myWin = NULL; }
  }

public:

  //! Create a window handle.
  bool CreateDefaultWindow()
  {
    myWin = createWglWindow (L"TmpGlWindow");
    if (myWin == NULL) { return false; }
    myDevCtx = ::GetDC (myWin);
    if (myDevCtx == NULL) { return false; }
    if (!WglWindow::SetWindowPixelFormat (myDevCtx, -1)) { return false; }
    myGlCtx = ::wglCreateContext (myDevCtx);
    return myGlCtx != NULL && ::wglMakeCurrent (myDevCtx, myGlCtx);    
  }

  //! Wrapper for SetPixelFormat().
  static bool SetWindowPixelFormat (HDC theDevCtx, int theFormat)
  {
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR aFormat = {};
    aFormat.nSize = sizeof(aFormat);
    aFormat.nVersion = 1;
    aFormat.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL;
    aFormat.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    aFormat.cColorBits = 32;
    const int aFormatIndex = theFormat == -1 ? ::ChoosePixelFormat (theDevCtx, &aFormat) : theFormat;
    if (aFormatIndex == 0)
    {
      std::cerr << "Error: ChoosePixelFormat() failed, Cannot find a suitable pixel format.\n";
      return false;
    }

    if (theFormat != -1) { ::DescribePixelFormat (theDevCtx, aFormatIndex, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), &aFormat); }
    if (::SetPixelFormat (theDevCtx, aFormatIndex, &aFormat) == FALSE)
    {
      std::cerr << "Error: SetPixelFormat(" << aFormatIndex << ") failed with error code " << GetLastError() << "\n";
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

public:
  //! Dummy window procedure.
  static LRESULT WINAPI dummyWinProc (HWND theWin, UINT theMsg, WPARAM theParamW, LPARAM theParamL)
  {
    return ::DefWindowProcW (theWin, theMsg, theParamW, theParamL);
  }

  //! Create a window handle.
  static HWND createWglWindow (const wchar_t* theTitle)
  {
    WNDCLASSW aWinClass = {};
    aWinClass.lpszClassName = L"OpenGL";
    static HINSTANCE anAppInstance = NULL;
    if (anAppInstance == NULL)
    {
      // only register the window class once
      anAppInstance = GetModuleHandleW (NULL);
      aWinClass.style = CS_OWNDC;
      aWinClass.lpfnWndProc = dummyWinProc;
      aWinClass.hInstance = anAppInstance;
      aWinClass.hIcon   = LoadIconW (NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
      aWinClass.hCursor = LoadCursorW (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
      if (!RegisterClassW (&aWinClass))
      {
        std::cerr << "Error: RegisterClass() failed, cannot register window class.\n";
        return NULL;
      }
    }

    HWND aWin = CreateWindowExW (WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE, aWinClass.lpszClassName, theTitle,
                                 WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
                                 2, 2, 4, 4, NULL, NULL, anAppInstance, NULL);
    if (aWin == NULL) { std::cerr << "Error: CreateWindow() failed, Cannot create a window.\n"; }
    return aWin;
  }

private:
  HWND  myWin;
  HDC   myDevCtx;
  HGLRC myGlCtx;
};

int main()
{
  HWND  aTestWin = WglWindow::createWglWindow (L"GLWindow");
  HDC   aDevCtx  = ::GetDC (aTestWin);
  HGLRC aGlCtx   = WglWindow::CreateCoreProfile (aDevCtx, false);
  if (aGlCtx != NULL)
  {
    std::cout << "[WGL] OpenGL vendor string: "   << ::glGetString (GL_VENDOR)   << "\n";
    std::cout << "[WGL] OpenGL renderer string: " << ::glGetString (GL_RENDERER) << "\n";
    std::cout << "[WGL] OpenGL version string: "  << ::glGetString (GL_VERSION)  << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note that code snippet tries creating a Core Profile of highest 4.x or 3.x version (for the case, when engine is extensible and wants to use as match functionality as possible), which can be omitted, if you need only exact version.